# How can I access public constructor of private nested class C++

Tags: c++, private, inner-classes

I have a **nested private** classes `Nested` and `Key` and I want that I could using my `add_new_object(Key, Nested)` function add objects to my `my_mmap` multimap. But when I try to call that those classes constructors, obviously that it's **inaccessible**. How can I solve the problem.

```cpp
class Enclosing
{
private:
    class Nested {
        string m_str;
        double m_dbl;
        bool m_boolean;
    public:
        Nested(string str, double dbl, bool boolean) :m_str(str), m_dbl(dbl), m_boolean(boolean) {};
    };
    class Key {
        int m_number;
        string m_name;
    public:
        Key(int num, string name) :m_number(num), m_name(name) {};
    };

    Enclosing* singleton;

    std::multimap<Key, Nested> my_mmap;
public:
    void add_new_object_to_mmap(Key k, Nested n) {}


    static Enclosing* get_singleton() {
        static Enclosing instance;
        return &instance;
    }
};
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: what is `Key` and `Nested`? why did you declare them in the private section? Note that one can get their types because they appear as arguments of a public member function.

Comment: without a [mcve] nothing is really obvious ;) The reason you cannot call the constructor is because there is no definition of `Key` or `Nested`

Comment: Do you want the classes to be private? Or do you really want private member instances of those classes? It would also help to show the definitions of `Nested` and `Key`.

Comment: Derived classes and the outside world cannot access `private:` items.  If you want the outside world to access the nested classes, declare them as `public:`.  If you only want derived classes to access them, declare the nested classes as `protected:`.  My recommendation is not to use nested classes, as it adds complexity to your project and complex programs are prone to more defects and harder to debug.

Comment: I don't want to someone could create an object outside the ``my_mmap`` multimap.

Comment: Sorry for that bad question formalization. Its my first question on StackOverflow.

Comment: The you need to add a public function to Enclosing that returns a Nested. But a probably better solution would be to have `add_new_object_to_mmap` take the arguments to create a nested and forward them to the constructor instead of taking a Nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what it means to declare a type in the private section. Or at least you are not aware of the implications of those types appearing as arguments of a public member function.

Here is your code with definitions added (without a definition for `Key` and `Nested` you cannot call their constructor at all):

```
#include <map>


class Enclosing
{
private:
    class Nested {};
    class Key {};

    Enclosing* singleton;

    std::multimap<Key, Nested> my_mmap;
public:
    void add_new_object_to_mmap(Key k, Nested n) {}

    
    static Enclosing* get_singleton() {
        static Enclosing instance;
        return &instance;
    }
};
```

Because the type `Key` and `Nested` appear in the public interface of `Enclosing` they are not actually private. Only their names are private. It is possible to infer the two types from the member function:

```
template <typename F> struct get_types;

template <typename K,typename N> struct get_types< void(Enclosing::*)(K,N)> {
    using Key = K;
    using Nested = N;
};
```

Now you can call their constructor like you call the constructor of any other type:

```
int main()
{
    using Types = get_types<decltype(&Enclosing::add_new_object_to_mmap)>;
    using Key = Types::Key;
    using Nested = Types::Nested;
    Enclosing::get_singleton()->add_new_object_to_mmap(Key{},Nested{});
}
```

[Complete Example](https://godbolt.org/z/1vE8nb5dh)

Finally, note that the caller doesn't even have to have names for the two types. This works as well (or with parameters when there are no default constructors):

```
Enclosing::get_singleton()->add_new_object_to_mmap({},{});
```

A type declared in the private section of another class is not private when it appears in the public interface. If you really wanted to hide the two types from the user of `Enclosing` then you need to do something else. See Teds answer for how to pass only parameters to be passed to their constructor to the public `add_new_object_to_mmap`. Then the two types can be truly private.

Comment: Thanks you **A LOT**, I'm going to implement this into my origin code and try it. 

P.S.
Can you tell a little about the stuff in ``template <typename K,typename N> struct get_types< void(Enclosing::*)(K,N)>``

Like what is going on this line of code? I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Artem well I wasnt really suggesting to use this `get_types`. It was only to show that your types arent really private. Your question is based on a misunderstanding. What you really need I dont know. I'd suggest to make `Nested` and `Key` simply `public`

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to be able to construct `Key` and `Nested` using a constructor taking 1 argument each, you could make `add_new_object_to_mmap` into a member function template and forward the arguments to the actual constructors:

```cpp
#include <utility>

class Enclosing {
private:
    class Key {
    public:
        Key(int);
        bool operator<(const Key& rhs) const;
        // ...
    };

    class Nested {
    public:
        Nested(double);
        // ...
    };

    std::multimap<Key, Nested> my_mmap;

public:
    template<class Karg, class Narg>
    void add_new_object_to_mmap(Karg&& karg, Narg&& narg) {              
        my_mmap.emplace(std::forward<Karg>(karg), std::forward<Narg>(narg));
    }

    static Enclosing& get_singleton() {
        static Enclosing instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

```cpp
int main() {
    /*here I want to call constructors*/
    Enclosing::get_singleton().add_new_object_to_mmap(1, 3.141);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ran5a695j)

---

To support constructing `Key` and `Nested` with a variable amount of arguments, you could use `std::piecewise_construct`:

```cpp
    template <class... Args>
    void add_new_object_to_mmap(Args&&... args) {
        my_mmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
```

and [forward the arguments as tuples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple):

```cpp
int main() {
    Enclosing::get_singleton().
        add_new_object_to_mmap(std::forward_as_tuple(1, "Foo"),
                               std::forward_as_tuple("Str", 3.141, true));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q5jGn7E6e)