# Adding elements to a map with user-defined key and set of objects C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I have a `std::map` that is encapsulated in a class, and the map consists of the **user defined** keys and **sets** of objects.

I have a function `void add_new_object_to_map(/*parameters that I need to accept*/)` that adds an element to the map.

Earlier, I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205459/how-can-i-access-public-constructor-of-private-nested-class-c/72205676?noredirect=1#comment127575309_72205676), but I had a map of **Objects** and not **sets of objects**.

My code:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

class Enclosing {
private:
    class Key {
        int m_number;
        std::string m_name;
    public:
        Key(int num, std::string name) :m_number(num), m_name(std::move(name)) {};

        bool operator<(const Key& rhs) const {
            return std::tie(m_number, m_name) < std::tie(rhs.m_number, rhs.m_name);
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Key& k) {
            return os << '{' << k.m_number << ',' << k.m_name << '}';
        }
    };

    class Nested {
        std::string m_str;
        double m_dbl;
        bool m_boolean;
    public:
        Nested(std::string str, double dbl, bool boolean) :m_str(std::move(str)), m_dbl(dbl), m_boolean(boolean) {};

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Nested& n) {
            return os << n.m_str << ',' << n.m_dbl << ',' << n.m_boolean;
        }
    };

    std::map<Key, std::set<Nested>> my_mmap;

public:
    template <class... Args>
    void add_new_object_to_mmap(Args&&... args) 
    {
        my_mmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void print() const 
    {
        for (auto& itr : my_mmap)
        {
            std::cout << "Key for this set:" << itr.first << "\n\n";
            for (const auto& elem : itr.second)
            {
                std::cout << elem << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    static Enclosing& get_singleton() {
        static Enclosing instance;
        return instance;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Enclosing::get_singleton().add_new_object_to_mmap(std::forward_as_tuple(1, "Key" ),
        std::forward_as_tuple("Value", 1.6, true));
}
```

Now I want to modify that function to be able to insert values inside map. But I don't have an idea how to do that. I tried to modify the code by myself, but mostly get the similar errors, like:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'std::set<Enclosing::Nested,std::less<Enclosing::Nested>,std::allocator<Enclosing::Nested>>::set(std::initializer_list<Enclosing::Nested>,const std::less<Enclosing::Nested> &,const std::allocator<Enclosing::Nested> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [6]' to 'std::initializer_list<Enclosing::Nested>'   bruh    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\utility   268
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `add_new_object_to_mmap()` with arguments to construct 1 `Key` and 1 `Nested` object.  But the `mapped_type` of your `std::map` wants a `std::set` of `Nested`  objects, not a single `Nested` object.  You can't construct a `std::set` from a (list of) object(s) unless you wrap it/them inside a `std::initializer_list`, as the error message says:

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [6]' to 'std::initializer_list<Enclosing::Nested>'

You can't pass in a fully-prepared `std::set<Nested>` object into `add_new_object_to_mmap()`, since `Nested` is `private`.

And `add_new_object_to_mmap()` can't create a local `std::set<Nested>` to pass into `my_mmap.emplace()`, since you can't extract the individual `tuple`s from a variadic parameter pack without using helpers.

So, try creating a helper to convert the variadic parameter pack into something your `std::map` can better digest, eg:

```
template <class... Args1, class... Args2>
void add_helper(
    std::tuple<Args1...> key_args,
    std::tuple<Args2...> value_args )
{
    Key key(std::get<0>(key_args), std::get<1>(key_args));
    Nested value(std::get<0>(value_args), std::get<1>(value_args), std::get<2>(value_args));
    std::set<Nested> s{value};
    my_mmap.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(s));
}
      
template <class... Args>
void add_new_object_to_mmap(Args&&... args) 
{
    add_helper(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Things will get much trickier if you want `add_new_object_to_mmap()` to add multiple `Key`+`Nested` pairs into the `std::map`.  Best to keep it simple and only insert 1 pair at a time.

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/CcVc0e)

Comment: Thank you. It really helped and I also watched a little more information about the structure bindings and really understood the code.

Comment: I just tried to insert another element to a set and it didnt work (yeah, I know that I'm writing this a little late). There's only the first element I added. Maybe you can help me again?